# How find $\sum_{0 \leq k: \leq 100 \ gcd \left( k, 100 \right) =1} f \left( \frac{k}{100} \right)$ if $f \left( x \right) = \frac{9^x}{3+9^x}$ ?

Tags: functions

How find of $\sum_{0 \leq k: \leq 100 \ gcd \left( k, 100 \right) =1} f \left( \frac{k}{100} \right)$ if $f \left( x \right) = \frac{9^x}{3+9^x}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove $(k,100)=(100-k,100)$

Now prove $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$

Set $x=\dfrac k{100}$

Now $\phi(100)=\phi(25)\cdot\phi(4)=40$

If $\displaystyle S=\sum_{0\le k\le 100;\left( k, 100 \right) =1} f \left( \frac k{100} \right),$

$\displaystyle  S+S=\sum_{0\le k\le 100;\left( k, 100 \right) =1}\left[f \left( \frac k{100} \right)+f \left( \frac{100-k}{100} \right)\right]=\sum_{0\le k\le 100;\left( k, 100 \right) =1}1=40$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:if x is relatively prime with 100,then (100-x) also is.